# How can I store a date into my database via formbuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine, entity

I try to store a date in my database:

```
$entity->setTimestamp(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', "2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00"));
```

But I get the error message:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Documents::setTimestamp() must
>   implement interface DateTimeInterface, boolean given,

The function in my entity:

```
  public function setTimestamp(\DateTimeInterface $timestamp): self {
    $this->timestamp = $timestamp;
    return $this;
  }
```

Comment: `\DateTime::createFromFormat()` Returns boolean  FALSE on failure. Your format string does not match the date string.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: The correct answer is `$entity->setTimestamp(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', "15.08.2005"));`

Answer (score 0):

Your format and date time is incorrect. use the following code

```
$date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', "2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00");
$entity->setTimestamp($date_time->format("d.m.Y"));
```

Also this will be simple string. So make changes to your `setTimestamp` function. Or else you can return entire `$date_time`.

Comment: with Symfony / Doctrine you set dates with date objects, and let Doctrine handle the conversion to database value

Comment: Now the error is `App\Entity\Documents::setTimestamp() must implement interface DateTimeInterface, string given,`

Comment: The correct answer is $entity->setTimestamp(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', "15.08.2005"));

Comment: Yeah you were correct. But what if the user doesn't want to change the format? You can still use `$date_time`, if you want DateTime interface.